# Generalized associative law

Tags: set-theory, associativity

In Naive Set Theory book of Halmos there is a statement that if $\{I_j\}$ is a family of sets with domain $J$ and $\{A_k\}$ is a family of sets with the domain $K = \bigcup_{j \in J}I_j$ then
$$\bigcup_{k \in K}A_k = \bigcup_{j \in J}(\bigcup_{i \in I_j} A_i)$$
which is a generalized version of the associative law for unions.

Now the question is how to see and interpret the generalization? What additional information carries this generalization over the usual associative law $(A \cup B) \cup C = A \cup (B \cup C)$

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is unclear exactly?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I can't understand where the generalization happens? For me the first equation looks like $A_1 \cup \dotsc \cup A_k = (A_1 \cup \dotsc \cup A_m) \cup \dotsc \cup (A_l \cup \dotsc \cup A_k)$. While for me the generalization should show that all combinations of paranthesising hold.

Comment: Yes, that what it shows. No matter how you split the indices of $K$, it will be the same union.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, ohh, I got it! Thanks! Can't understand why my own reasoning wasn't enough to see it. Really this annoys me that I can't see such simple idea behind the equality. You may write this as the answer.